# Zoom text in listview row android android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am increasing the size of my listview on button click but when a button is clicked, some listview item's textview size remains default and is not changed according. Any idea ? Here is a piece of my code for increasing font size in listview.

```
int count = mlist.getChildCount();

if (zoom_counter==1){
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        Button textTab=(Button)mlist.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        // if your control is not textview, use your correct one
        textTab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,16f);
        efficientadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: how about getting the font size into a variable inside the adapter class as a static variable. then wen you call notifydatasetchanged, change the side of the textviews inside the adapter itself.

Comment: textTab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,16f); Its work, it seem you doing some other mistake